# Bring Android app back from background programmatically

Tags: java, android, background

I'm new to Android coding but I already had played with java.

I want to open or bring my app back once it is in background.

I've been searching around but nothing seems to work.

I have a function of a class that is called every time a notification is received which is **CordovaNotificationReceivedHandler** and it is instantiated by the OneSignal init as per the code below.

```
OneSignal.init(this.cordova.getActivity(),
              googleProjectNumber,
              appId,
              new CordovaNotificationOpenedHandler(notifOpenedCallbackContext),
              new CordovaNotificationReceivedHandler(notifReceivedCallbackContext)
      );
```

Trying to get my application to be reordered and displayed, even if the user is in another application, I made the following changes:

```
OneSignal.init(this.cordova.getActivity(),
              googleProjectNumber,
              appId,
              new CordovaNotificationOpenedHandler(notifOpenedCallbackContext),
              new CordovaNotificationReceivedHandler(this.cordova.getActivity(), notifReceivedCallbackContext));
```

In the body of the function that is called when receiving a push notification I added the following code:

```
Intent it = new Intent("intent.my.action");
      it.setComponent(new ComponentName(contextActivy.getPackageName(), MainActivity.class.getName()));
      it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      contextActivy.getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);
      this.handleActivityLifecycleHandler();
```

Como a classe ficou após a modificação:

```
private class CordovaNotificationReceivedHandler implements NotificationReceivedHandler {

    private CallbackContext jsNotificationReceivedCallBack;
    private Context contextActivy;

    public CordovaNotificationReceivedHandler(Context contextActivy, CallbackContext inCallbackContext) {
      jsNotificationReceivedCallBack = inCallbackContext;
      this.contextActivy = contextActivy;
    }

    @Override
    public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
      Log.w("Got here","Aqui");

      Intent it = new Intent("intent.my.action");
      it.setComponent(new ComponentName(contextActivy.getPackageName(), MainActivity.class.getName()));
      it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      contextActivy.getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);
      this.handleActivityLifecycleHandler();

      try {
        CallbackHelper.callbackSuccess(jsNotificationReceivedCallBack, new JSONObject(notification.stringify()));
      }
      catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }
    } 
}
```

The problem is that the application is not reordered to be applied or opened.

**It is important to remember that I am assuming that the application should be open.**

Comment: Your app is already started and you want it back in the focus again, basically closing another app.
This can only be done by sending a notification and the user can click on the notification. There is no way to get the application back in focus without the interaction of the user

Comment: So, passenger apps like Uber use custom notification or fullscreenintent to open a notification and then the user can decide? My app already recieves notifications but I'd like to be sure the user is aware of that content of notification to make a decision.

Comment: fullscreenintents seems to be a good way, it would be quiet annoying if any developer can force their app in the foreground by sending an intent. The user always has to have a choice if they are interested or not, but you can use ways to catch their attention. Sounds, vibration, fullscreenintents or whatever is possible, but you are not allowed to have more power over the device than the user. When the user clicks on the notification you can start your app. I don't know out of my head which flag you need to set, but you can look it up at the Intent documentation.

Comment: @DominikWuttke I forgot to mention you

Comment: @DominikWuttke I got it. So I'm gonna go to FullScreenIntents. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this, It work fine.**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("intent.my.action");
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, yourActivity.class));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Don't Forget Add this in your activity in manifest

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="intent.my.action" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```